# Visual Studio Code - MS python intellisense - indent / newline

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, pep8

I am a bit new to programing, and the VS code editor is doing something that I cannot get to work my way.

I am writting in python with the Microsoft intellisense & pylance installed, and after disabling all the extensions one by one, I found the culprit it was intellisense that was linebreaking my code in a strange way. I understand that pep8 is the standard formatter used by intellisense, but I have a feeling this isn't the normal way that is happening in my workspace.

See how at line 34 & line 14 has a "weird" newline added? This is all over my code and this isn't read friendly, but look at line 24, that line has a longer line. I am missing something, and don't know how to fix this.

Take a look at the second image, as I have manually adjusted the line break that intellisense does when i press save, Notice that live 34 is shorter and also starts at the same column as line 24, but yet only line 34 gets a line break.

Can someone help with this issue?

[image: Screen grab of Visual studio workspace]

[image: Manually adjusted linebreak line 24]

Comment: PEP-8 has a section for maximum line length [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) and if you exceed that, it breaks your statements with newlines. Is your problem with the way it breaks your lines?

Comment: Ok, how come line 24 is so long? Line 29 is shorter than line 24.

Comment: Is line 24 longer than 79 or 72 characters?

Comment: I put the cursor at the end of line 24 and it says in the bottom right of the screen Ln 24, Col 99

Comment: With the cursor at the first letter ( Yield ) the Column is 13. I add this information because i don't know it pep8 counts white spaces also, as I mentioned I am new to this. I do know about the concepts of the pep's, but not in detail yet about the pep8 standard.

Comment: Hello Ali,

Thanks for the help thus so far. I have added an extra image to the original post for comparison, and some more explanation to the original post. As you will see, the line 24 is treated differently from line 34?